# How to zoom out past view bounds with UIscrollview in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to make a UIscrollview that can zoom out beyond the original frames of the view that it hosts. Here is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit


struct MapWrapperView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    private var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 100
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
        scrollView.bounces = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        
        let hostedView = context.coordinator.hostingController.view!
        hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        hostedView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        hostedView.frame = scrollView.bounds
        scrollView.addSubview(hostedView)
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(hostingController: UIHostingController(rootView: self.content))
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.hostingController.rootView = self.content
        assert(context.coordinator.hostingController.view.superview == uiView)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Coordinator
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>
        
        init(hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>) {
            self.hostingController = hostingController
        }
        
        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return hostingController.view
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
            if(scale < scrollView.minimumZoomScale){
                scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale
            }
            
            if(scale > scrollView.maximumZoomScale){
                scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scale
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

I can successfully zoom out farther than the bounds of the subview, but when this occurs the subview zooms out from the top left of the screen and begins to act strangely. Is there any way to either a) make the subview zoom out from the center of the screen and then extend to the new bounds or b) perhaps set the scale of the subview to a smaller value in the beginning and then set a reasonable minimum zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have figured out an answer. Basically, according to other members of stackoverflow, the contentOffset and contentInset variable have to be changed dynamically with every pinch in order to manage where the content anchors the  zoom. Here is the changed code to make this work:

```
//
//  MapWrapperView.swift
//  Saturday
//
//  Created by Bruce Jagid on 6/22/21.
//

import SwiftUI
import UIKit



struct MapWrapperView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    private var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 100
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
        scrollView.bounces = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        
        let hostedView = context.coordinator.hostingController.view!
        hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        hostedView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        scrollView.bounds = hostedView.frame
        scrollView.addSubview(hostedView)
        
        let leftMargin: CGFloat = (scrollView.frame.size.width - hostedView.bounds.width)*0.5
        let topMargin: CGFloat = (scrollView.frame.size.height - hostedView.bounds.height)*0.5
        
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: max(0,-leftMargin), y: max(0,-topMargin));
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: max(hostedView.bounds.width, hostedView.bounds.width+1), height: max(hostedView.bounds.height, hostedView.bounds.height+1))
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(hostingController: UIHostingController(rootView: self.content))
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.hostingController.rootView = self.content
        assert(context.coordinator.hostingController.view.superview == uiView)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Coordinator
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>
        
        init(hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>) {
            self.hostingController = hostingController
        }
        
        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return hostingController.view
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
            if(scale < scrollView.minimumZoomScale){
                scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale
            }
            
            if(scale > scrollView.maximumZoomScale){
                scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scale
            }
            
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if(scrollView.zoomScale < 1){
                let leftMargin: CGFloat = (scrollView.frame.size.width - hostingController.view!.frame.width)*0.5
                let topMargin: CGFloat = (scrollView.frame.size.height - hostingController.view!.frame.height)*0.5
                scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: max(0, topMargin), left: max(0,leftMargin), bottom: 0, right: 0)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the scroll view zooms out past the content view bounds, the zoom will be centered, as per the logic within the scrollViewDidZoom delegate function.

Comment: I guess my next question is how do I make this view still allow me to zoom into certain areas outside of the bounds of the subview?

Comment: Nevermind I figured that out as well, just made the initial scale of the subview small, so it starts zoomed out. The Scrollview automatically maps that to a scale of 1, so it zooming in and out does not change anything